# Flutter - "build web" results in no gradient, but "run -d chrome" has gradient

Tags: flutter, dart

The screenshot says it all.

On the left is `flutter run -d chrome` and the blue gradient, which is a result of `BoxDecoration` being added to a `Container`.

On the right is `flutter build web` followed by `firebase deploy --only hosting`. The `build web` command runs with no errors and the `deploy` command uploads with no errors, but the gradient, as you can see, is gone, resulting in a gray background.

Since flutter does not produce any typical html files or css that I can find it is pretty much impossible to inspect or find why the gradient is not working in the produced web files. Any thoughts on what I am missing with `flutter build web` considerations or is this a bug that needs to be reported to flutter?

```dart
/// In class "TopClipper"
static get gradient => const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topRight,
        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        colors: [
          Color(0xFF333F7A),
          Color(0xFF9CBCD9),
        ],
      ),
    );

/// This ClipPath and call to gradient is in another file
/// that is in a SliverPersistentHeader delegate.
ClipPath(
  clipper: TopClipper(),
  child: Container(
    /// Calling static "gradient" above.
    decoration: TopClipper.gradient,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: expandedHeight,
    child: const Spacer(),
  ),
)
```

### UPDATE and FIX

Thanks to @IvoBeckers comment regarding an unexpected gray background being indicative of an error, I checked the logs, which I should have paid more attention to, even though it did render, minus the gradient.

And sure enough there was an `EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY` pointing to my incorrect use of `Spacer()` as the only child of `Container()`. It was unnecessary as well because the container will grow to it's set width/height anyway.

**Removing `Spacer()` removed all errors and now `flutter run -d chrome --release` displays the gradient.**

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: TopClipper(),
  child: Container(
    /// Calling static "gradient" above.
    decoration: TopClipper.gradient,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: expandedHeight,
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: What about `flutter run -d chrome --release` ? I'm assuming the firebase one makes release builds and the other one debug builds. I've ran into issues before that only were in release builds. I don't know where the problem is for you, but it might push you in the right direction if this is a debug vs release thing

Comment: `flutter run -d chrome --release` results in no gradient. So the issue is with `--release`, but where do I start to fix this?

Comment: that's a good question. I'm not sure what to do. I would try to see if it helps to not use a gradient from the static getter and just write out the decoration in place, just to see if it has any effect. I don't know what else you can try. And also, even if it fixes the issue I have no idea why that would fix it. It might be a bug in flutter

Comment: Removing static getter, and hardcoding the `LinearGradient` still results in no gradient for `--release`.

Comment: Wish I could help you more, but I'm also clueless now

Comment: [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92719) it says that grey parts of the screen might indicate a crash or something.

Comment: @IvoBeckers see my updated post with the fix based on errors I missed in the logs when running `flutter run -d chrome`.